# Why do projects built with the old Kinect SDK fail to run on the latest version?

Tags: kinect

I have a game which was built on the older versions of the Kinect SDK. It doesn't seem to work on the latest Kinect SDK v1.6. I get many errors.

What are the changes that I need to make, so I can play the game using the Kinect sensor?

Comment: Doesn't work as in...? It doesn't compile? It compiles, but doesn't want to run at all? It runs sort of, but crashes at some point? It summons dragons that burn down the entire village? If you don't give us details on what exactly the problem is, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Several changes were made to the SDK in version 1.5, which breaks coded from older versions.  The namespace has changed and how the skeleton is stored and referenced changed quite a bit.  Other items changed too, and I am not aware of a complete comprehensive list.

Depending on the code you may just need to modify a few things, or really dig into the code more.  Know that many of the errors you are getting are probably the same error happening multiple times.  Fr example, when the skeleton is being referenced - it happens a lot, but after you fix it once you can easily fix it again and quickly.

You need to *understand the latest SDK* first.  I suggest working through many of the examples, which do a good job of showing the basics.  Then you can work through the game code and start to see how things are not referenced correctly... and fix them.